# Highcharts 4.0.3 stacked bar chart bug adds â-

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I updated my Highcharts to 4.0.3 today and most of the change seems flawless except it adds a `â -` to my stacked bar charts. Is there a fix for this?

**Chart code:**

```
                        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
                            {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'bar',
                            renderTo : 'chart',
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: categories
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Count'
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            reversed: true
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                stacking: 'normal'
                            }
                        },
                            series: [{
                            name: 'Successes',
                            data: success
                        }, {
                            name: 'Failures',
                            data: failures
                        }]
                    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 4.0.3 code there is this in a couple of places:

```
<span style="color:{series.color}">â—</span>
```

In older versions it looks like this:

```
<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span>
```

Looks like a bug (encoding messed up somehow).  Try changing it.